# Spring mapper with Java Map

Tags: java, spring, lombok, mapper

I've been struggling with the following issue for a few hours now, and I can't figure it out how to make it work:

Spring mapper, in order to convert DB response to DTO:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ITeamResponseToDtoMapper {

    TeamResponseDTO toDto(TeamResponse teamResponse);

}
```

TeamResponse class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TeamResponse {

    private Map<String, List<NameAndType>> teamList;
}
```

NameAndType class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class NameAndType{

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String team;
}
```

TeamResponseDTO class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TeamResponseDTO {

    private Map<String, List<NameAndTypeDTO >> teamList;
}
```

NameAndTypeDTO class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class NameAndTypeDTO {

    private String name;
    private String type;
    private String team;
}
```

Basically, 'NameAndType' and 'NameAndTypeDTO' are the same, why it fails to do the conversion?

```
error: Can't map property "java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<com.microservices.teamservice.dataobjects.NameAndType>> teamList" to "java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<com.microservices.teamservice.api.dataobjects.NameAndTypeDTO>> teamList". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method:
```

Comment: If you look into it, com.microservices.teamservice.api.dataobjects.NameAndTypeDTO and com.microservices.teamservice.dataobjects.NameAndType, both class with different package. It means you are getting as different class and trying to map into another one.

Comment: Which `@Mapper` is this? The `[mapper]` you tagged with is unrelated.

Comment: I guess it is `MapStruct` mapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to explicit add methods to map the whole chain of classes. On your example the following should work:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ITeamResponseToDtoMapper {

    TeamResponseDTO toDto(TeamResponse teamResponse);

    List<NameAndTypeDTO> natListToDTO(List<NameAndType> natList);

    NameAndTypeDTO nameAndTypeToDTO(NameAndType nameAndType);

}
```

regards,
WiPu

Comment: Interesting, this actually solved the issue. 
Thank you for that.